# Difference between XposedBridge.log() and Log.d();

Tags: logging, xposed-framework

As the title implies, why should I use XposedBridge.log() and not ordinary Log.d()?

I suppose it is when Log.d() isn't ready or something, but when is that?

Answer (score 1):

All I can see from the code is it calls Log.i/d etc with tag as Xposed

https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/blob/art/app/src/main/java/de/robv/android/xposed/XposedBridge.java

The xposed framework app reads the logcat with this tag and you can see the filtered log in the app itself.